# How to call all the excel file in a folder and run through the pythons one by one and have the results save in one excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

So basically I have multiple excel files (different names) in a folder and I want to copy the same cell (for example B3) from all files and create a column in New excel file and put all the value there.

[image: Import File]

The file above is what I want to import (multiple files like that). I want to copy the names and emails and save it to the new file like the one below.

[image: export new file]

Comment: How far have you got/how much have you tried? Can you read from a single file using python? Can you list the files in a directory from Python?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to read multiple files, get a specific cell and then create a new data frame and save it as a new Excel file:

```py
cells = []
for f in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    cells.append(data.iloc[3,5])
pd.Series(cells).to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

In my particular example I took cell F4 (row=3, col=5) - you can obviously take any other cell that you like or even more than one cell and then save it to a different list, combining the two lists in the end. You could also have more complex logic where you could check one cell to decide which other cell to look at next.

The key point is that you want to iterate through a bunch of files and for each of them:

- read the file
- extract whatever data you are interested in
- set this data aside somewhere

Once you've gone through all the files combine all the data in any way that you like and then save it to disk in a format of your choice.

Comment: So I tried the method you mentioned above but it is giving me a name error:  name 'glob' is not defined. Is there anything I need to import first??

Comment: yes, import `glob`